# doctrine PostPersist & PostUpdate in one listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine, listener

I am using a listener for persisting **and** updating from doctrine.

Only issue is, that when the listener is called it creates and updates a new/current entity,
So therefore it calls itself again, which creates two entities.

The only way I can think to stop this is to have a global variable that would know if we are persisting(creating) an entity and not call use the update listener.

I know this is wrong and there must be a better way to create a listener that updates and creates other entities without calling itself again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to avoid a recursive loop with doctrine listeners is to have the listener remove itself from the event manager before doing any updating/persisting.

So for example in some code I've worked on I have something like this:

```
// $evm is the Event Manager grabbed from the Entity Manager that
// is part of the Event passed to the listener function
public function removeThyself($evm)
{
    $evm->removeEventListener(Events::postFlush, $this);
    $evm->removeEventListener(Events::onFlush, $this);
}

public function readdTheyself($evm)
{
    $evm->addEventListener(Events::postFlush, $this);
    $evm->addEventListener(Events::onFlush, $this);
}
```

Where these functions remove the event listener from any events the listener is registered on.

Then before doing anything from the listener that affects the database I call these to make sure the event listener does not get called. e.g.

```
// $em is the Entity Manager, $evm is the Event Manager
$this->removeThyself($evm);
$em->flush($toFlush);
$this->readdTheyself($evm);
```

Comment: When I do `addEventListener` it seems to call the listeners again? I am doing a flush at the end of the listener, I can add remove listener in and it will not re-call, but if i add the add listener after everything it seems to still duplicate

Comment: @AndrewAtkinson I'm not sure I understand. Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: It's ok, a few hours and it was solved, the main issue for me was the fact that when i tried to remove the listener it was actually a different object (but the same class) so '$this' did not work.